# Recorder Service Error: Left Mouse Down: Failed to find matching element - Xcode error

Tags: xcode, macos, automation, record, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate my mac app by XCTest. While trying to record the app from XCode, I got this error message:

[image]

This happens when I tap on a button. The button hierarchy is..

Button -> Stack View -> NSView

Here, button is the subclass of NSButton, I added buttons in a stack view. That stack view was added in myView(Subclass of NSView).

P.S: Each button has image view and a label in it.

**Question:**

- When I tap on the button, the app crashes with the above alert. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Having the same problem in Xcode 8.

Comment: This error happens when I try to access or try to do operations on an element, which is not in the view hierarchy / which is not having any accessibility values (Label,Value,ID). One way to find the problematic element is, note the element that you accessed before this crash, and inspect the element to check its accessibility values in Accessibility Inspector.