# How to automate mac app using Xcode?

Tags: ios, macos, appium, ui-automation, xctest

I try to add UI test cases to our existing mac application. I already tried UI test cases for iOS, which includes the following steps

- I choosed **Appium** instead of Apple's **UIAutomator**, because I want to maintain the same flow for our Android apps too.
- To proceed the automation, I need to set *Labels/Values/Identifiers* to the elements. So that they can be accessible. We used `drawRect` method in most parts, so I followed [this](http://ronnqvi.st/making-drawrect-accessible/) post to make drawed components accessible.
- I can set/read elements in iOS. What I did is, whenever I draw an element, I simply created an `UIAccessibilityElement` and added in the corresponding view.

Now, I'm trying to write UI tests for our mac application. As **Appium** does not have support to the mac application, I considered to use Apple's **XCTest** UI recording/playback to automate my mac application.

Here is the steps that I took:

- `NSAccessibility` is the class that provides accessibility to the mac application
- With **XCTest**, If I knew a particular elements (say a button) identifier/label, I can proceed with automated tap action
- Unlike `UIAccessibility`, `NSAccessibility` is a role based object. That is, we need to mention which type of accessibility element that we are going to define.
- To start the automation process, I took my mac applications left panel, which has five buttons aligned vertically in it
- I set *identifiers* to those buttons. Then I opened **Accessibility Inspector** and opened my mac app. The values are properly set.
- Then I tried to use record option in **XCTest**. When tapping the button, crashes the app with the error

> "Recorder Service Error: Left Mouse Down: Failed to find matching
>   element".

I posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632518/recorder-service-error-left-mouse-down-failed-to-find-matching-element-xcode).

Questions:

- Can someone suggest me the right path to automate mac application? Am I going in the right way?
- I googled a lot to see a working sample code about how to implement `NSAccessibility`. But I can not found anything. Can someone share any useful links/samples?
- All I need is, to get elements by *identifier/label*. **Accessibility Inspector** shows the right value where as **XCTest** can not read the *identifiers*. Did anyone face this issue?

Thanks in Advance